# rails view helper each with separator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, separator

I'm sure I saw a while back a rails helper method where .each in the view accepts a separator such as a comma.

So say I want:

```
- @results.each do |result| 
  = result.title

#to output
result 1, result 2, result 3
```

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think

```
@results.map(&:title).to_sentence
```

should do the job. [See docu.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions/to_sentence)

Comment: Awesome that's the one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are refering to, but:

```
@results.collect { |r| r.title }.join( ',' )
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer but to_sentence is what I was looking for. Purely pedanticism mind you. :)

Comment: I agree. to_sentence is new to me too, so I'm glad I came here.